# How to get a count for number of items in a Gmail seach

Tags: gmail, usage-statistics

When you search in Gmail it appears that any search over the number displayed (e.g. 50) will show "50 of many" instead of the total number.

There is an option to go to most recent messages, but the option to go to the oldest messages is disabled (visible but greyed out).

I tried smaller searches and it seems that nothing over 50 will show the total number.

I found an answer to my own question when searching on the subject. (See below)

P.S. Why would I care how many messages there are in a search result?  I want to figure out if messages are disappearing with a clear statistic.  Some messages seem to have disappeared with no clear cause.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This solution does not actually work.  Following just the first three steps of Tony's solution is not sufficient.  It shows a number that looks absolute, but that number changes depending on how many screens you have viewed.  Doing all the steps gives a larger number, but still an inconsistent one.

===
Thanks to Tony Abou-Assaleh, I found the answer:

http://tony.abou-assaleh.net/tech-tips/counting-gmail-search-results

I only needed the first three of his steps to get a conversation count:

1. Do a search, either regular or advanced through the “Show search options” link.
2. Select all the results by hitting “Select: All”
3. Really select ALL the results by clicking on the “Select all conversations that match this search” link

The total number of conversations appeared in the message pane.

Comment: This is good for the number of conversations, but not number of emails in those.

Comment: @NateS You can turn off the option to show emails grouped as conversations. The conversation view setting is under the settings gear / all settings. 
Z Yoder's suggestion worked for me to start with, but now it's back to showing > 50. I don't see any reason as to why it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a label following the instructions at this link worked for me (though I had to move the relevant messages out of the trash first):

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/06/find-number-of-gmail-search-results.html